# How to update Geofencing list of points in iOS into Background

Tags: ios, notifications, push, geofencing

I would create an iOS application with geofencing.

Can I send a new list of geofencing points to this app through Apple Server in Background or must I launch the app to update its list of points ?
More easily, can I from an external server change the geofence point without launching the app ?

Thanks you very much.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app doesn't use any of the available background modes, you can't change them remotely. The push notifications are received and shown by the OS, and only opening them will trigger your app to load and execute your code.